# "Basic" Proof of Riemann Lebesgue Lemma

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Can someone provide a proof of the Riemann Lebesgue Lemma that doesn't make use of the known integral of $e^{itx}$? In particular I'm looking for the solution to the following problem:

Show that $\hat{f}(t)$ (the Fourier transform) “vanishes a infinity” on R. Hint: the Lebesgue measure is “outer regular”. We also have that the Fourier transform is a bounded continuous function, that $f(x) \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R},B)$, and that $f(x)e^{itx}$ is also integrable.

Outer regularity means that:

$\forall A$ $\mu(A) = inf\{\mu(B): B $ is open and contains $A \}$.

Intuitively this happens because the wavelength of each wave becomes arbitrarily small, and I think the way I'm suppose to approach is is to replace $f(x)$ with a function that approximates it, so we have the integral of some simple function $f_n$ times $e^{itx}$, but I don't know how to use outer regularity, or even move in a useful direction from here.

(As a note, this was homework, but it has already been turned in. Just really want to know how to do it!)

Answer (score 1):

For compactly supported smooth functions, you can truly integrate by parts. Doing so and taking absolute values, you get a factor of $1/|\xi|$ times an integral involving the derivative which is convergent.

Then you have that compactly supported smooth functions are dense in $L^1$. Picking an $\varepsilon$-approximation $g$ of your given $L^1$ function $f$, you can do the usual triangle inequality trick:

$$\left | \hat{f}(\xi) \right | = \left | \int f e^{-i \xi x} \right | = \left | \int (f-g) e^{-i \xi x} + \int g e^{-i \xi x} \right | \leq \left | \int (f-g) e^{-i \xi x} \right | + \left | \int g e^{-i \xi x} \right |.$$

Now the second term is already tending to zero by the integration by parts, while the first term is (regardless of $\xi$) at most $\varepsilon$ by the $L^1$ approximation and a triangle inequality use.

(This is pretty much what the Wikipedia article says, by the way.)

Comment: I know that's what the Wikipedia article says- I haven't gotten that far into Lebesgue Integration, which is why I asked for an answer phrased in the way I mentioned.

Comment: @Anthony I'm really not sure how to do this starting from something as "low level" as outer regularity. If I had to do this without the density result given, I would prove the density result first. It follows by convolving your nonsmooth function with a mollifier and then checking the convergence. About the only additional analytic tool that is required is Fubini's theorem. You probably saw something of this character already, before you were familiar with Lebesgue integration.

Comment: @Anthony I suppose you could start by approximating just by a continuous compactly supported function, which is easier to do with outer regularity. Then recall that you can approximate a continuous function by smoother functions.

Comment: I'm pretty unfamiliar with all this language... But thanks for your help!

Comment: @Anthony Try the last idea, approximating by compactly supported continuous functions. If you get stuck, look up Lusin's theorem (one of the few foundational theorems of measure theory, which is proven using the regularity of measure).

Comment: I feel like I've see compactly supported functions in some theorem, but when We've talked about simple functions they've just had finite range. Where is this compact coming from?

Comment: Compactly supported means zero outside a compact set. For instance, in a sigma-finite space we can assume simple functions have this property when we use them in approximation. Here we want it so that when we integrate by parts, there is no boundary term.